# When runing 'npm run build' I get an error that says "'CI' is not recognized"

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, continuous-integration

I'm working on a project and when I try to run `npm run build` I get an error that says "'CI not recognized". I've been looking for an answer and I'm not able to find anything.

1. This is what I get in gitbash:

   ```
    'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! barhop@0.1.0 prebuild: `CI=true react-scripts test --colors`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the barhop@0.1.0 prebuild script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Juan Mireles\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-16T20_05_42_295Z-debug.log
   ```
2. This is my package.json:

   ```
   {
     "name": "project",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
       "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
       "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
       "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
       "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
       "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
       "react": "^17.0.1",
       "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
       "react-placeholder-image": "^0.1.8",
       "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
       "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
       "router": "^1.3.5",
       "serve": "^11.3.2",
       "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "prebuild": "CI=true react-scripts test --colors",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
       "predeploy": "npm run build",
       "deploy": "vercel --prod"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": [
         "react-app",
         "react-app/jest"
       ]
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: That's not how you set environment variables in Windows. If you need to run scripts cross-platform see e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 2):

Change your build script to the following:

```
"build": "set CI=false && react-scripts build"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Windows, you need to change your prebuild.

```
"prebuild": "set CI=true&react-scripts test --colors",
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#on-your-own-environment

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "CI" and it helped.

( "build": "react-scripts build")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).